# user roles in an array error

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I am hoping somebody can explain to me why I get the error:

'Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given'

with the following code:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
  if ( in_array( 'teacher','student', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
  //
}
```

I have also tried to use:

```
$roles = array('student','teacher');
$user = wp_get_current_user();
  if ( in_array( $roles, (array) $user->roles ) ) {
  //
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can include more than one role in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

you need to provide first parameter as `string`, second one the `array` in which you want to search and third one which is optional is `type of search`.

So apply a `foreach()`:-

```
$roles = array('student','teacher');
$user = wp_get_current_user();
foreach ($roles as $role){
  if ( in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles ) ) {
     // do your stuff
  }
}
```

Note:- this will only works when `$user->roles` will be a one-dimensional 
array.

Answer (score 1):

the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for `in_array` clearly shows you that it accepts only 1 needle and 1 haystack parameter.

what you need to do is something like this (there will be many ways).

```
function checkForRole($roles, array $array) {
    foreach($roles as $role) {
        if(in_array($role, $array) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

if(checkForRole($roles, (array) $user->roles)) {
    // do something
}
```

**edit**

just to add (and I didnt know this, so thanks for making me look it up), `in_array` can use an array as the needle, but it searches the haystack for the whole array, so this example returns true:

```
in_array(['a','b'], [['a','b']]); // note the multidimensional array haystack
                       ^   ^
```